# CSS Dropdown menu doesn't show up in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, navigation, html-lists, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out why my dropdown menu won't show up in Internet Explorer 7.  For example, in Firefox, the links under the Attorney Profile button show up fine on hover, but not in IE7.

CSS: http://pastebin.com/geCXmaz2

Website: http://josephruscitti.com/clients/gare/

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only adding a top value to your submenu on hover when it should be on the main rule itself so once you add it your menu works fine:

**CSS**

```
.mymenu li ul {
  top:100%;
}
```

Comment: When I add a top value there, the submenu doesn't appear at all in either browser.

Comment: @Joseph apply `position:relative;` to the parent li, e.g. `.mymenu li { position:relative; }` .. just tested it out and it works for me.